# iOS 4 - Using blocks as a member of a class

Tags: objective-c, ios4, typedef, objective-c-blocks

I was hoping someone could help me understand the syntax of blocks when used as members of a class. I have some code that's actually working just fine:

```
@class Structure;
typedef void (^StructureDeleteCallback)(Structure *);

@interface StructureListDelegate : NRFCTableDelegate
{
    StructureDeleteCallback _structureDeleteCallback;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) StructureDeleteCallback structureDeleteCallback;

@end
```

This works, but I would like to understand the syntax of the `typedef` statement; and whether or not it's actually required to use typedef.

What I've read says that using `typedef` in this situation is recommended because it makes the code a lot clearer; but I've been unable to get it to compile at all when trying to do this without `typedef`. My understanding of typedef was that the syntax was basically:

```
typedef [actual type] [new name for type];
```

Such as:

```
typedef double CLLocationDegrees;
```

But the syntax of my `typedef` statement doesn't match this. So my questions are:

- How can the syntax of my `typedef`
  statement be so different from other
  `typedef` statements / what does the syntax I'm using actually mean to the compiler?
- Is it possible to
  have a block as a member of a class
  without using `typedef`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I myself have asked a question along the lines of yours here: [Block references as instance vars in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230271/block-references-as-instance-vars-in-objective-c)

See my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148253/is-it-possible-to-define-a-block-as-a-member-of-a-class/4148309#4148309) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118285/nscomparisonresult-and-nscomparator-what-are-they/4118298#4118298).

Comment: Ah! I wasn't able to get it to work without using typedef because I didn't realize the syntax for defining the iVar would be completely different. I thought I'd still have to have [typename] [iVarName];

Comment: So just to clarify one last thing... whether it's in the typedef, or just declaring a block, is it basically just that blocks have a different syntax for declaring them than other types do? The compiler just sees the ^ symbol and knows that the name of the variable is after the ^, as opposed to after the name of the type like it is with int x;? Thanks!

Comment: Had to step away for a bit. Thanks again!